# Why is 30MHz Clock signal distorted on oscilloscope?

Tags: fpga, oscilloscope, frequency-measurement, ccd

I'm trying to probe a 30MHz clock signal, coming from an FPGA and routed to a CCD sensor.

There are no other components, other than connectors, between source/destination.

When I probe this signal with my oscilloscope, I get a distorted waveform which over shoots and undershoots. The probes I am using are the standard tektronics probes that come with the MSO2024B that we have. They have been calibrated to the scopes 5khz test point and show no overshoot.

[image: Distored 30MHz Clock Signal]

The clock signal should be 3.3V peak to peak.

The scope probe ground clip is connected to the 0V reference point near the regulator for the 3v3 rail.

I am investiagting why we are seeing noise on our power supplies after the FPGA has powered up and starts providing the 30MHz clock to the external CCD.

Comment: Because 30MHz is a pretty high frequency composed of even higher frequency harmonics, getting filtered out by different components, wires and probes on it's way to the scope display.

Comment: "The scope probe ground clip" don't use the ground clip.

Comment: Seems like a pretty standard waveform when you don't probe propperly. A clock waveform should be probed with the spring ground clip of a probe connecting to the ground of the clock (which shouldn't be to far away in the first place). The loop area of those clip-type probes is simply too large to allow proper probing of the high-frequency components of a 30MHz clock signal.

Comment: Using X10 probe or X1 probe? Don't use X1 probes for anything but very low frequencies...

Answer (score 20):

There are two issues here: Bandwidth and Measurement technique.

**Bandwidth**: 
Your measured signal is bandwidth limited. A 30MHz square wave has lots of harmonic content and your scope has a relatively low bandwidth (200MHz) so the higher frequencies are attenuated and you only see the sum of the first few odd-order harmonics (30MHz, 90MHz, 150MHz, ...).

Here is a square wave approximation made up of the 1st, 3rd, and 5th harmonics (taken from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32310/what-exactly-are-harmonics-and-how-do-they-appear) which looks quite a bit like the trace you posted: [image: square wave approximation]

Tektronix has a Technical Brief on this subject that might be of interest:

[Understanding Oscilloscope Bandwidth, Rise Time and Signal Fidelity](https://www.ece.ubc.ca/~robertor/Links_files/Files/TEK-Understanding-Scope-BW-tr-Fidelity.pdf)

---

**Measurement Technique**:

You are using a rather long ground clip which contributes to overshoot. [This answer to another E.SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/80038/88422) illustrates the improvements in measured overshoot by using a spring clip on the scope probe tip instead of the longer ground tip.

Before: 
[image: Initial measurement]

After: 
[image: Measurement with spring tip]

Here is the measurement setup:
[image: Measurement setup]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't know about the probe properties, as well as filters or bandwith. I hope this tiny tutorial about them will explain it for me.

### The fourier transform

Brief introduction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Fourier_analysis

30 Mhz square signal contains lots of higher frequency sine signals -even the 30 Mhz one!- to make the original square signal. This is an example extracted from wikipedia:

[image: Fourier transform of a square wave]

The image represents a part of the spectrum of the input signal. The entire spectrum is infinty.

Well, your signal is not at 1 KHz, but you can multiplying it 30000 times and nailed it.

### Filters

Brief introduction in wikipedia Filter_(signal_processing)

When you select part of the signal spectrum, you are filtering it. Even when you don't select a part of the signal spectrum, you are filtering it.

### The probe bandwith

Brief introduction in wikipedia Bandwidth_(signal_processing)

Your measurement probe has a bandwith. The bandwith means that all the frequencies from 0 Hz to the bandwith MHz are measurable. Obviously, the higher frequencies are not. That means you are selecting, from all original frequencies, only a part of them, because the probe is a proper filter.

If you want to see a complete square wave 30 MHz signal with a 150 MHz probe (as I'm assuming your probe is), you simply can't, and will display 2 components of the original square wave.

Hope it helps.